# What is the best way to Sort Forge/BIM360 Docs files lists?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am currently in the process of implementing pagination, sort and search functionalities in the project files/plans/sheets views of BIM 360 Docs integration.

Since I couldn't find any best practices regarding to these features, I thought I would reach out so that I don't keep stuck reinventing the wheel.

**Background:**

Most of the implementation uses https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/ SDK.

Based on what I saw it looks like there is no built-in results sorting in the Forge/BIM 360 APIs. BIM 360 Docs looks as if it sorted results on the client.

One has to cache all the results as structured data on the client in order to provide the sorting functionality.  That also does not play well with any pagination approach.

**Question:**

Is there a way to sort results using the API, so that they come back in a predefined order, also while paginating?

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get back to you A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

According to our engineering team, the "sort" feature isn't currently supported by Forge Data Management API. Apologizing for the inconvenience caused.

I have logged a request **FDM-1813**[Support sorting in APIs of BIM360 integration] in our internal system to our engineering team to allocate time to evaluate the possibility. As it required some time to complete this task, please remember this request id for the future reference. You're welcome to track updates or provide additional information by quoting this request id via `forge.help@autodesk.com`.

However, a workaround is to fetch all data from the API, then sorting on the client side via Javascript.

Cheers,